# Generator keeps returning the same value [JS]

Tags: javascript, function, generator

I wonder why this code outputs the same value every time. Seems like nothing's wrong here.

```js
function* infiniteList() {
  let count = 0
  while (true) yield count++
}
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) console.log(infiniteList().next().value)
```

Comment: `infiniteList()` starts a new generator. You get the first value of it then start a new generator and get the first value of it. 100 times.

Answer (score 5):

You are re-creating your iterator in every loop iteration.

You need to create it once and then reuse it to get the next element:

```js
function* infiniteList() {
  let count = 0
  while (true) yield count++
}
let mylist = infiniteList();
for (let x = 0; x < 100; x++) console.log(mylist.next().value)
```